# Get image from any directory in HTML?

Tags: html, mysql, image, apache

I tried doing an error 404 page, but I need an image with it.
When I do example.com/(something random) then it displays the 404 error image, else, if I do example.com/(something random)/(something random), it does not display the image. What I am asking is: does HTML (using xampp) have a root directory? So like `xampp/htdocs/404.png`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether is it mandatory to keep the images in a directory the answer is NO.But it's better to keep it in a directory inside your `htdocs` folder, so that even the link that you are setting as the image `src` is deleted you can still use the image since the image is already downloaded and stored in a directory and you just have to access the image.

And if you are using an image it's always better to add a description for the image so , in a scenario like the image is deleted or the `src` path is changed it will show you the type of image that was inserted there.

Ex:

```
->htdocs
   ->project
      ->images
         ->van.jpg
         ->car.jpg
      ->code
         ->1.html
         ->2.html
```

in a folder structure like above you can set the image path as:

```
<img src="../images/van.jpg." alt="van" width="500" height="600">
```

By using `alt` will display the description(van) that is set for the image, if the image is corrupted.

Comment: Well, what I am asking is that for example the user when he has a 404 page, I want to display an image but the 404 directory could be .com/random/random or /random so we don't know how to access the image like "../image.png". I am asking if there would be a reference directory, Like "C:/xampp/htdocs/image.png". Thanks,